# How to extract all the current video files and its address in the web page with js?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping

```
 var imgs=document.images.length;
```

It can extract all the images on the web page.
How extract all the flv files whose suffix is flv such as `sample.flv` in the web page with js?Not all the flv files on my local directory but web page.
The plugin `Video DownloadHelper` in firefox can get the current mp4 file.
[image]
Why my js code can't do the same task?

```
var Links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".mp4"]');
console.log(Links);
```

[image]

How to extract the current video files with js such as the plugin `Video DownloadHelper` in firefox?

Comment: What do you meany by ***flv files***  ?

Comment: Do you mean Flash Video? Those aren't images.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be simple, flv files are usually used within a plugin or player of some kind rather than as "part of the document". It may be helpful to post more information about the page this is being used on as at the moment I think this will be a tough question to answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Yahoo Movies](https://www.yahoo.com/movies) use blob stream to transfer video data. There are no direct `mp4/flv` links anywhere, nor can you get such links directly. The `src` of the `<video>` tag refers to a blob stream link:

```
<video class="yvp-html5-video" preload="" id="2413371376" src="blob:https://www.yahoo.com/1dfafd99-a1ff-4cc8-bcff-255e69db9977"></video>
```

When you hit to download MP4 from `Video DownloadHelper`, the plugin actually reads the blob stream and writes it to disk in an MP4 file. It doesn’t download a MP4 file. If you try to `Copy URL`, you’ll get something like this to your clipboard:

```
https://roarack01.vpg.cdn.yimg.com/yahoomovies/61fb473f-04a2-381e-b2ae-9496dfba5e66_VYtMtix1DscECbXMT9tHT7yf2P9BZF-mRCMjBejFgALFHl7NSm1ZXPOMICAOr949v2xUgEASYLw-_1_0_vtt.m3u8?a=yahoomovies&ib=sapi&m=application%2fvnd.apple.mpegurl&mr=0&ns=c+i+ci+cii&vid=61fb473f-04a2-381e-b2ae-9496dfba5e66&x=1479599999&s=370695a7063b6aae06fb7f537c85773a
```

You can record a blob stream, but it’s not an easy task.

For more details on video blob stream, check these links:

[What is blob in the <video src=blob:url>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389001/what-is-blob-in-the-video-src-bloburl)

[Export HTML5 blob video to MP4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202373/export-html5-blob-video-to-mp4)

[W3C Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)

[A URL for Blob and File reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to look for all the links which have an associated `.flv`.

If you want this, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and select all the links ending in .flv using the css selector `$=`.

```
var flvLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".flv"]');
```

Comment: That will only select anchor links to an flv file, I doubt it works for any sort of embedded video.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought he was asking for. If not, he will need to retrieve in some way the files the server and look for the flv files.

Answer (score 0):

to get all flv files of a directory, please try the following code -

```
var files = fs.readdirSync("YOUR_DIRECTORY");
var path = require('path');

for(var i in files) {
   if(path.extname(files[i]) === ".flv") {
       //do your desired task here
   }
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect all video requests on Chrome -> Networks tab in Media sub tab.